# Joomla 3.0 JForm "value_field"

Tags: xml, joomla

I have a Jform that I am using for the administrator area. The component is for Joomla 3.0.

This code is located in the model/forms and it is an xml file

This is the code I have

```
<field name="winnerid"
        query="SELECT `id`,`surname` ,`firstname` FROM #__squashladder_playerinfo ORDER BY `surname`"
        type="sql"
        key_field="id"
        value_field="firstname"



        id="winnerid"
        onchange="winnerrating(this.value)"
        default="0"
        label="Winner ID"
        description="Winner ID"  > 
         <option value="0">Select Winner</option> 

         </field>
```

I have tried a few ways, but I cant get first and last name to be in the "value_field" area.

Currently it just shows firstname, I want it to show firstname then a space and surname.

Can I put php in this area to combine them or do I have to do something else??

Comment: Can you put this as an answer and then accept it so that it's clear to people who have the same issue you've solved it please :) Thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

Well I just found out how to do it for anyone else wanting to know, you just have to do it in the sql query.

```
query="SELECT id, concat(surname, ' ',firstname) as firstname FROM #__squashladder_playerinfo ORDER BY surname"
```